# Get JSON response XMLHTTP alternative

Tags: json, excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have a working code in which I used XMLHTTP API request
This is the code

```
Const sURL As String = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=258"
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, json As Object, r As Long


Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
r = 2

With http
    .Open "Get", sURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .setRequestHeader "user-key", "APIKEY"
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    Set json = JSONConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
```

Is there an alternative to get the JSON response without using the XMLHTTP library (as this doesn't work on MAC)?
Thanks advanced for help.

Comment: ? https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: Thanks  alot. I have downloaded the file `VBA-Web - Installer` then Browse for my excel file that has the code and everything is installed correctly. I guessed that I have to use `Set json = WebHelpers.ParseJson(.ResponseText)` instead of using `JSONConverter` and this works fine. One point, I don't know how to alternate is the XMLHTTP?

Comment: @QHarr  Can you show me example of how to use Web-Tools to send HTTP request ..?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Yes and I have read a lot but lost because as you know English is not my native so this would take too much time for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to configure it and make it work

```
Sub Test()
Const sUrl As String = "https://reqres.in/api/users/2"
Dim Response As New WebRequest, Client As New WebClient, rObj As Object, json As Object

Client.BaseUrl = sUrl

With Response
    .Method = WebMethod.HttpGet
    .RequestFormat = WebFormat.json

End With

Set rObj = Client.Execute(Response)
Set json = WebHelpers.ParseJson(rObj.Content)

Debug.Print rObj.Content
Debug.Print json("data")("email")
End Sub
```